# Nearest cell with value below a defined value in excel

Tags: excel, data-analysis

I have a column of values ranging from approximately `-20 to 20`. Within these values I have certain collections forming "peaks" (if the data were to be graphed), like this:

-7.431377404
 -0.123504621
 8.267563041
 11.90999127
 10.14175866
 1.613639202
 -7.170097474
 -6.826058515

I define anything which is part of a "peak" to be above a value of 3. How do I select all the values within one "peak" and choose the maximum? In the example above, I would want the value of 11.91 to be chosen. There are various examples of these "peaks" across my data. For example, here's another:

0.571340419
 0.543676911
 3.162139566
 4.132734389
 1.649930702
 -0.201880797

And here I would want `4.13` to be chosen. I have too much data to do every single one of these by hand.

Essentially, if I imagine my data on a graph, I want something which chooses the tip of every single peak. Can this be done?

Many thanks.

Comment: Is there any criteria that separates each set of data from each other?  For example, how do we know to start at `-7.431...` and end at `-6.826...` in your first example?  Is there a date or some identifier?  Stated in a different way, how do you differentiate between collections?

Comment: Also - do you mean only peaks, or also valleys? ie in your example above, if there was a value -12.1, would you want that chosen instead of 11, because it has a further distance from 0?

Comment: There is no criteria, aside from it being further on in the column of data that I have, if that's what you mean? It's all part of one big set. And yes, only peaks. Not valleys.

Comment: @MattS To clarify - does this mean that if you had data that went 1,2,2,2,3,3,4,3,2,5,6,-1,3,1 you would have 3 different groups of data, with peaks of 4,6, 3? because there are 3 different ranges, where a range is defined as a group of continuous cells of at least 3?

Answer (score 0):

This formula will find the value of the peak in your data, assuming it is all one 'set' of data, and assuming it is located in column A:

```
=MAX(A:A)
```

This will further check to ensure that this value is at least 3:

```
=IF(MAX(A:A)>=3,MAX(A:A),"")
```

This will further give you the location of that cell, if it matters to you (will give the row number):

```
=IF(MAX(A:A)>=3,MATCH(MAX(A:A),A:A,0),"")
```

**Edit** to determine the individual peak within each group of continuous cells of at least +3. This is a non-array formula solution as Tom Sharpe has already provided that alternative below. If you understand Array Formulas, that is likely your preferred solution.

First use a helper column - this will count up each time it enters a new range of at least 3. In cell B1, hardcode to 1. In cell B2 enter the following and drag down:

```
=IF(AND(A1<3,A2>=3),B1+1,B1)
```

This checks if the last row was less than 3 and the current row is at least 3. If that's true, then this is a new grouping.

Then in column C, starting at C2, put the following and drag down - this will keep a running check for what the highest value in that grouping is [hardcode C1 as C1=A1]:

```
=IF(B2=B1,MAX(A2,C1),A2)
```

Then for any given grouping, use this formula to see the highest peak there[In the example here, it checks for the highest peak within the 5th grouping]:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(5+1,B:B,0))
```

Will need to be played around with for first and last values, but this is the general idea. Again, Array Formula solution is probably preferred.

Comment: I think this will give the global maximum and OP is after local maxima

Comment: @MattS could you clarify how you determine what a 'set' of data really is? In your comment there you say "its all part of one big set"... what does that mean?

Comment: It's a single column of values, approximately 8000 of them.

Comment: I think it's good to number the peaks like Grade 'Eh' bacon has done. I can probably simplify my formula if I do the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of thing I'm thinking about:-

```
=IF(A2>=3,MAX(INDEX(A$1:A1,MAX(ROW(B$1:B1)*(B$1:B1=FALSE))):INDEX(A3:A$15,MATCH(FALSE,B3:B$15,0))),"")
```

to be entered in C2 as an array formula and pulled down.

I first set all the cells in column B to FALSE if column A <3 and TRUE if >=3, so it's supposed to search through each peak from the last FALSE up to the next one.

[image]

It can be made easier if the peaks and troughs are numbered starting with 1 in B2 and using this formula from B3 onwards:-

```
=IF(OR(AND(A2>3,A3<=3),AND(A3>3,A2<=3)),B2+1,B2)
```

Then this non-array formula can be used starting in C2:-

```
=IF(A2>3,MAX(INDEX(A$1:A1,MATCH(B2-1,B$1:B1))
:INDEX(A3:A$15,MATCH(B2+1,B3:B$15,0))),"")
```

[image]